# How to get Trusted CA in Apache 2.4.4 mod-ssl // reloading CRL without restart httpd

Tags: c, apache, ssl, openssl, certificate

I used to work with a patched Apache 2.2.17 which allowed me to reload the CRL with no need to restart my server.

But it seems since Apache 2.3.15-beta, CRLs are delegated to OpenSSL (sc->server->crl does not exist anymore...)... and I can't see how to adapt my patch to my 2.4.4.

Here are the piece of code I can't use with my new version of apache (and openssl 1.0.1e)

**before :**

```
void refresh_revocation_store(server_rec *sr, apr_pool_t *pool)
{
    SSLSrvConfigRec *sc = mySrvConfig(sr);
    int reload = 0;

    /* Some stuff to determine if my crl needs to be reloaded */
    ... 
    reload = 1;
    /*************/
    if (reload) {
        X509_STORE *old, *new;
        new = SSL_X509_STORE_create ((char *)sc->server->crl_file,
                                     (char *)sc->server->crl_path));
        old = sc->server->crl;
        sc->server->crl = new;
        X509_STORE_free(old);
    }
}

STACK_OF(X509) *extract_CAs(STACK_OF(X509_OBJECT) *sk)
{
  STACK_OF(X509) *skx = sk_X509_new_null();
  X509_OBJECT *tmp;
  int num, i;

  if(sk) {
    num = sk_X509_OBJECT_num(sk);
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      tmp = sk_X509_OBJECT_value(sk, i);
      if(tmp) {
        if(tmp->type == X509_LU_X509) {
          sk_X509_push(skx, tmp->data.x509);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return skx;
}

STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *extract_CRLs(STACK_OF(X509_OBJECT) *sk)
{
  STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *skx = sk_X509_CRL_new_null();
  X509_OBJECT *tmp;
  int num, i;

  if(sk) {
    num = sk_X509_OBJECT_num(sk);
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      tmp = sk_X509_OBJECT_value(sk, i);
      if(tmp->type == X509_LU_CRL) {
        sk_X509_CRL_push(skx, tmp->data.crl);
      }
    }
  }
  return skx;
}


void ssl_verify(X509_STORE_CTX *ctx, void *dummy)
{
    STACK_OF(X509) *trusted_CAs = NULL;
    STACK_OF(X509) *untrusted_CAs = ctx->untrusted;
    STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *crls;
    SSL *ssl = (SSL *)X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data(ctx);
    conn_rec *conn = (conn_rec *)SSL_get_app_data(ssl);
    SSLSrvConfigRec *sc = mySrvConfig(conn->base_server);
    server_rec *s = conn->base_server;
    int ok;
    ssl_mutex_on(s);
    trusted_CAs = extract_CAs(sc->server->ssl_ctx->cert_store->objs);
    if(sc->server->crl) {
        refresh_revocation_store(s, conn->pool);
    crls = extract_CRLs(sc->server->crl->objs);
    } else {
       crls = sk_X509_CRL_new_null();
    }
    /* Starting the chain */
    if (ctx->chain == NULL) {
        ctx->chain = sk_X509_new_null();
    }
    ok = is_valid_cert(ctx, trusted_CAs, untrusted_CAs, crls, ctx->cert, 0);
    sk_X509_free(trusted_CAs);
    ssl_mutex_off(s);
    return (ok == X509_V_OK) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

**And now it would something like this (but does not work, I don't no why)**

```
void refresh_revocation_store(server_rec *sr, apr_pool_t *pool)
{
        SSLSrvConfigRec *sc = mySrvConfig(sr);
        int reload = 0;

        /* Some stuff to determine if my crl needs to be reloaded */
        ... 
        reload = 1;
        /*************/
        if (reload) {
            store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(sc->server->ssl_ctx);
            if (!store || !X509_STORE_load_locations(store, 
                                                     sc->server->crl_file,
                                                     sc->server->crl_path)) {
            ssl_log_ssl_error(SSLLOG_MARK, APLOG_INFO, sr);
            ssl_die(sr);
            }
        }
    }
}

STACK_OF(X509) *extract_CAs(STACK_OF(X509_OBJECT) *sk) {...} // Same as before
STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *extract_CRLs(STACK_OF(X509_OBJECT) *sk) {...} // Same as before

int ssl_verify(X509_STORE_CTX *ctx, void *dummy)
{
    STACK_OF(X509) *trusted_CAs = NULL;
    STACK_OF(X509) *untrusted_CAs = ctx->untrusted;
    STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *crls;
    SSL *ssl = (SSL *)X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data(ctx);
    conn_rec *conn = (conn_rec *)SSL_get_app_data(ssl);
    SSLSrvConfigRec *sc = mySrvConfig(conn->base_server);
    server_rec *s = conn->base_server;
    int ok;
    ssl_mutex_on(s); 
    X509_STORE *store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(sc->server->ssl_ctx); 
    if(store) {
        refresh_revocation_store(s, conn->pool);
        crls = extract_CRLs(store->objs);
    } else {
        crls = sk_X509_CRL_new_null();
    }
    /* Starting the chain */
    if (ctx->chain == NULL) {
        ctx->chain = sk_X509_new_null();
    }
    trusted_CAs = extract_CAs(sc->server->ssl_ctx->cert_store->objs);
    ok = is_valid_cert(ctx, trusted_CAs, untrusted_CAs, crls, ctx->cert, 0);
    sk_X509_free(trusted_CAs);
    ssl_mutex_off(s);
    return (ok == X509_V_OK) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

If anyone has any idea... Please help! I'm going mad with that...

Cheers, 
Cheloute

Comment: Rather silly question - but how bad is it to do a simple, so called, 'graceful' restart ? That won't kill any worker still working - and for all intents and purposes is pretty much 'cost' free ?